# swift 3 - ios : convert anyObject to string

Tags: ios, swift, string, anyobject

How could we convert anyobject to string in swift 3, it's very easy in the older version by using.

```
var str = toString(AnyObject)
```

I tried `String(AnyObject)` but the output is always optional, even when i'm sure that AnyObject is not a optional value.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The compiler suggests that you replace your code with:

```
let s = String(describing: str)
```

One other option is available if you have a situation where you want to silently fail with an empty string rather than store something that might not originally be a string as a string.

```
let s =  str as? String ?? ""
```

else you have the ways of identifying and throwing an error in the answers above/below.

Answer (score 15):

Here's three options for you:

Option 1 - if let

```
if let b = a as? String {
    print(b) // Was a string
} else {
    print("Error") // Was not a string
}
```

Option 2 - guard let

```
guard let b = a as? String
else {
    print("Error") // Was not a string
    return // needs a return or break here
}
print(b) // Was a string
```

Option 3 - let with ?? (null coalescing operator)

```
let b = a as? String ?? ""
print(b) // Print a blank string if a was not a string
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a simple function ([repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/OutlyingStrictFirm)) that will mash any value into a string, with `nil` becoming an empty string. I found it useful for dealing with JSON that inconsistently uses `null`, blank, numbers, and numeric strings for IDs.

```swift
import Foundation

func toString(_ value: Any?) -> String {
  return String(describing: value ?? "")
}

let d: NSDictionary = [
    "i" : 42,
    "s" : "Hello, World!"
]

dump(toString(d["i"]))
dump(toString(d["s"]))
dump(toString(d["x"]))
```

Prints:

```
- "42"
- "Hello, World!"
- ""
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
let a = "Test" as AnyObject
guard let b = a as? String else { // Something went wrong handle it here }
print(b) // Test
```

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
var str:AnyObject?
str = "Hello, playground" as AnyObject?
if let value = str
{
   var a = value as! String
}
```

OR

```
var a = str as? String
```

Comment: You have to make sure that `AnyObject`has a value if you´re using `as!` otherwise it will crash.